# Why does my the listview position items wrongly?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm coding a scrollable `listview` in android with `textview` and `edittext` in each row. Because there's the issue when you scroll, that the new data gets lost i update my `ArrayList` in an `TextChangedListener` like this:

```
 TextWatcher txtwatch = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                if (!scrolling) {
                    InhalteArr.set(position, s.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };
```

My problem is now, that this method is working, but only for the seven first rows. The following rows are showing the right information, but they don't set the updated data at the right position in the `ArrayList`.

I can't understand why the first seven rows are doing what I want and the rest seems to begin setting the updated data upcounting from zero again and not going on with eight.

It's very creepy because all rows also the last rows seems to get the right data from ArrayList, but the last view rows are setting the data at wrong place in ArrayList.

In `getView()` Method I'm setting the data like this

```
viewHolder.Inhalt.setText(InhalteArr.get(position).toString());
but that works.
```

Has anyone any idea?
Thank you!

**EDIT:** Here's my adapter:

```
public class SyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> {
Typeface bahn = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/bahnschrift.ttf");
Typeface ih = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/corbel.ttf");

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView Merkmal;
    TextView Inhalt;
}

ArrayList MerkmaleArr;
ArrayList InhalteArr;
public SyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList Merkmale, ArrayList Inhalte) {
    super(context, R.layout.listanzeige, R.id.MerkmalT, Merkmale);
    this.MerkmaleArr = Merkmale;
    this.InhalteArr = Inhalte;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listanzeige, parent, false);

        viewHolder.Merkmal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MerkmalT);
        viewHolder.Merkmal.setTypeface(bahn);
        viewHolder.Inhalt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.InhaltT);
        viewHolder.Inhalt.setTypeface(ih);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    System.out.println("Aktuelle Position: " + position);
    viewHolder.Inhalt.setText(InhalteArr.get(position).toString());
    viewHolder.Merkmal.setText(MerkmaleArr.get(position).toString());
    return convertView;
}}
```

**EDIT2:** Now i figured out that all rows with position >7 have at the beginning already convertView != null, what means, that they skip the if (convertView == null) code. But why?

Comment: Please post the code for your Adapter.

Comment: override two methods `getItemId()` and `getItemViewTyoe()` and return position in both. check if it works in the adapter and yea post the adapter code

Comment: i added the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming size of InhalteArr and MerkmaleArr is same

Add this method to your adapter class

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return InhalteArr.size();
}
```

Adapter Class refinement Example:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listanzeige, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.Inhalt.setText(InhalteArr.get(position).toString());
    viewHolder.Merkmal.setText(MerkmaleArr.get(position).toString());

    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    final EditText Inhalt;
    final TextView Merkmal;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        Inhalt = v.findViewById(R.id.InhaltT);
        Merkmal = v.findViewById(R.id.MerkmalT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the size doesn't change

Comment: I can suggest you a change in your code for adapter class which for me worked.

Comment: that would be nice :D

Comment: Inhalt and Merkmal are TextViews?

Comment: Merkmal are Textviews and Inhalt are Edittexts

Comment: I have Updated the Answer again according to the Views you are having

Comment: thats working, but my problem is to set the data in the ArrayList and not on the textviews or edittexts

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem:
I solved my issue setting a tag out of the `if(convertview == null)`, at first i was trying to set the tags into that `if`method, but that won't work at all rows.

To get the `edittext's`tag into the `onTextChangeListener`i found some good code here at stackoverflow:

```
            View focView = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (focView != null) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) focView.findViewById(R.id.tvinhalt);
                if (edit != null && edit.getText().toString().equals(s.toString())) {
                    int positionof = Integer.parseInt(edit.getTag().toString());
                    System.out.println("Tag= " + positionof);
                    YouArray.set(positionof, s.toString());
                }
```

Hope with this answer you don't have to invest as much time as me to understand, that the tag must been set outside of that `if`function :D